# Switch on Enum in Java: unqualified enum constant

Tags: java, enums

I have this enum :

```
public class RemoteUnitType implements Serializable {

    public enum deviceVersion {
        ANDROID_AT1, 
        ANDROID_AT1_PRO, 
        ANDROID_AT5,
        ANDROID_AK1
    }
```

and I want to create a switch on Enum, like this

```
switch (remoteUnit.getDeviceVersion()) {
            case RemoteUnitType.deviceVersion.ANDROID_AK1 :
            break;  
}
```

But I got this error:

```
The qualified case label RemoteUnitType.deviceVersion.ANDROID_AK1 must be replaced with the unqualified enum constant
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do not need to qualify, just use the enumeration's label:

```
switch (remoteUnit.getDeviceVersion()) {
            case ANDROID_AK1 :
            break;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no language lawyer, but it seems to follow from the language definition. In my understanding, EnumConstantName is what you used in the enum's definition. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11

SwitchLabel:

```
case ConstantExpression :
case EnumConstantName :
default :
```